# UIPickerView does not appear on top

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am trying to implement `UIPickerView` and I have almost done it. But when I click on text field, picker view appears behind the text field. Here are the snapshots before and after showing picker view.

**Before** clicking on text field.

[image]

**After** clicking on the text field.

[image]

Here you can see that picker view is behind the text field. I want it to be on top.

**EDIT** Here is the code I am using to show picker view:

```
-(void) showPickerView 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.50];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.picker];

    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
    {
        CGRect frame = self.picker.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 151.0;
        self.picker.frame = frame;
        frame = self.toolBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 107.0;
        self.toolBar.frame = frame;
    }
    else if(iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
    {
        CGRect frame = self.picker.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 239.0;
        self.picker.frame = frame;
        frame = self.toolBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 195.0;
        self.toolBar.frame = frame;
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: image is not enough please share code that you are using for this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. In fact it was a plum mistake. I placed the `pickerView` before other views. So when it appears on screen, it appears behind the `textfield`. I had to put it at the bottom place in my `.nib` file.

In iOS, the view added before will go behind other views. I missed this concept.

Answer (score 1):

In your view hierarchy the textfield may be above pickerview. If you are using xib/storyboard then select pickerview and from menu select Editor>Arrange>Sent to Front.

If you are using code for creating all ui elements add pickerview after adding textfield. or

try

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:pickerView];
```

Comment: i am not using storyboard, I tried this one but still same result

Answer (score 0):

**use**

> [self.view bringSubViewToFront:pickerView]

you did't get than please share your code for more explanation we will help..